# How to solve the display problem of TI CCS?

Tags: linux, display, scaling, chromebook

When I attempted to install and run TI CCS (for MSP430) on my chromebook as a linux app, it just display like below:
[image: the window]

The icons are so large that they are covered by other components.

I've tried to adjust the scaling and resolution of chrome os but the issue still occurred.

Comment: It almost looks like the edit window needs to be resized to reveal the icons on the left? What version of CCS is this? Is this the online flavor or did you install the full (nearly 1G) Linux version of CCS?

Comment: It is installed via the online installer

Comment: Ooh, that complicates things a bit. I've not used the online installer, but have had some difficultly with the other TI online tools on Linux. My understanding is the online installer basically installs modules used by chrome/chromium to provide CCS, rather than the traditional IDE. A quick post to [TI CCS Forum](https://e2e.ti.com/support/tools/code-composer-studio-group/ccs/f/code-composer-studio-forum) will usually get you an answer in 24 hours.